# How to extract Convolution Parameter of a Pre-Trained Alex Net model using Caffe Framework

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe, convolution

I am working on some optimizations for making the Convolution layer and  the Fully Connected Layer work fast. I need the Convolution Kernel weights of a pre trained Alex Net model in order to perform the convolution with an actual image.

I tried extracting the kernel parameters of first Convolution layer by writing a simple python code.

```
# Load the original network and extract the fully connected layers'    parameters.
import caffe
import sys

f1=open('./testfile', 'w')

net = caffe.Net('models/bvlc_alexnet/deploy.prototxt', 
            '/media/ubuntu/sdcard/bvlc_alexnet.caffemodel', 
            caffe.TEST)

print >> f1, net.params['conv1'][0].data
```

This gives me the kernel weights of first layer of Alex Net but there is a discrepancy in the size of kernel.

My output file is something like this

```
[[[[ -2.83153467e-02  -6.76262565e-03   1.69464536e-02 ...,
 -1.89594068e-02  -1.02251852e-02   6.16483716e-03]
[ -3.29505093e-02  -1.28040602e-02   1.36566022e-02 ...,
 -2.06015427e-02  -3.66760854e-04   2.51943078e-02]
[ -3.83224562e-02  -1.63374413e-02   1.71793532e-02 ...,
 -2.37888489e-02   1.93770428e-03   3.10342778e-02]
...,
[ -1.32519063e-02   1.20311677e-02   1.48218526e-02 ...,
 -1.09308660e-02   1.10638803e-02   3.24864089e-02]
[ -1.22069763e-02   8.22285190e-03   1.70185007e-02 ...,
 -8.42322689e-03   1.14848586e-02   3.08694635e-02]
[ -3.33898212e-03   1.44736944e-02   9.51856188e-03 ...,
 -1.00268638e-02   6.68688724e-03   2.11901478e-02]]
```

As we have 96 kernels of size (11*11*3) in the first convolution layer of alex net the output expected is 96 kernels of size (11*11*3).

I do not get proper weights for second or even third convolution layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the Convolution Kernel weights, the issue was with the size of notepad file.

This is my modified code where I am printing the Kernel weights one by one in a loop.

```
import caffe
import sys 
import numpy as np

f1=open('./testfile', 'w')
print >> f1,"";
f1.close();
net = caffe.Net('models/bvlc_alexnet/deploy.prototxt', 
            '/media/ubuntu/sdcard/bvlc_alexnet.caffemodel', 
            caffe.TEST)
f1=open('./testfile', 'a')
for num in range(0,95):
    print >> f1,net.params['conv1'][0].data[num]
f1.close()
```

I got 96 kernels of size 11*11*3.

-Hope you find it helpful :)